# Fetching values from app.config on plugin click in VS 2012 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, plugins, app-config, t4

I have a plugin solution in VS 2012 IN C#. I have to execute T4 TEMPLATES on click of this plugin. These T4 TEMPLATES are using some variables which are defined as keys in key value pair in app.config file in the solution.

Problem is how to read values from `App.config` on click of plugin and then how to use these values in T4 templates.

Some one please help me by providing a simple sample code for accessing values from `app.config` on plugin click and code for accessing the retrieved value in T4 templates.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any built-in API that allows you to access config files at design time in Visual Studio in order to use them in T4 templates. You will have to open and read the .config file yourself:

1. Get a reference to your project via the Visual Studio Automation Interface (EnvDTE)
2. Find the Project Item that is the desired .config file
3. Parse the .config file with the Xml Api of your choice

You can also skip steps 1+2 and parse the .config file from its path, but that won't be very reusable.

If you don't want to deep-dive into that Automation model and stuff, have a look at [tangible's free T4 editor](http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/). It comes with a T4 Template gallery. There is a T4 file ready to be included in yours that provides you with the appSettings and connectionStrings from any .config file in your solution. Look for "tangible Visual Studio Configuration Helper". Using this your code might look like this:

```
<#
    var hostServiceProvider = this.Host as IServiceProvider;
    var dte = hostServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as EnvDTE.DTE;
    var project = dte.Solution.Projects.Cast<EnvDTE.Project>().First();
    var configHelper = ConfigurationHelper.GetDefaultConfiguration(project);

    foreach(var appsetting in configHelper.AppSettings)
    {
#><#= appsetting.Key #> = <#= appsetting.Value #>
  <#}
#>
```